# Qstring replace is not working fine

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

i want to replace temp.replace

```
(QString("/"), QString("\"));
```

Here i am getting error
error C2001: newline in constant
error C2275: 'QString' : illegal use of this type as an expression

How can i replace "/" with "\"

---

thakns 4 ur answer. But till now i didnt sort my issue. Please check my code

// Convert to a wchar_t*

```
size_t origsize = strlen(toChar) + 1;

const size_t newsize = 100;

size_t convertedChars = 0;

wchar_t wcstring[newsize];

mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcstring, origsize, toChar, _TRUNCATE);

wcscat_s(wcstring, L"\\*.*\0");

wcout << wcstring << endl; // C:\Documents and Settings\softnotions\Desktop\Release\*.*



SHFILEOPSTRUCT sf;

memset(&sf,0,sizeof(sf));

sf.hwnd = 0;

sf.wFunc = FO_COPY;

 //sf.pFrom =wcstring;  /* when giving wcstring i am not getting answer */

  sf.pFrom = L"C:\\Documents and Settings\\softnotions\\Desktop\\Release\\*.*\0";

   wcout << sf.pFrom  <<endl;   // C:\Documents and      Settings\softnotions\Desktop\Release\*.*
```

Both wcstring  and sf.pFrom are same then y not gettng answer when assigning sf.pFrom =wcstring;

Answer (score 10):

By escaping it with another `\`:

```
"\\"
```

This is a general C/C++ gotcha about how escaping works inside character strings. Since `\` is used for escaping and thus has a special meaning inside a string, it should be escaped itself.

---

The error thrown by your compiler is that it sees the second string constant going until the end of the line, since `\"` precludes it from ending the string.

Answer (score 4):

The help below is for Qt4 library!

If you need to normalize file absolute path you may use for you needs *toNativeSeparators* function. Here is the Qt Assistant information about it:

> **QString QDir::toNativeSeparators (
>   const QString & pathName )**   [static]
>   Returns pathName with the '/'
>   separators converted to separators
>   that are appropriate for the
>   underlying operating system.
>
> On Windows,
>   toNativeSeparators("c:/winnt/system32")
>   returns "c:\winnt\system32".
>
> The returned string may be the same as
>   the argument on some operating
>   systems, for example on Unix.
>
> This function was introduced in Qt
>   4.2.
>
> See also fromNativeSeparators() and
>   separator().